# $q^2=4m^2$ as the threshold for creation of a real electron-positron pair

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, propagator, s-matrix-theory, pair-production

On page 252, Peskin & Schroeder remark that the branch cut of the quantity

$$\widehat \Pi_2(q^2) \equiv \Pi_2(q^2)-\Pi_2(0) = -\frac{2\alpha}{\pi}\int_0^1dx\,x(1-x)\log\left(\frac{m^2}{m^2-x(1-x)q^2}\right)\tag{7.91}$$

beginning at

$$q^2=4m^2$$

is at the threshold for creation of a real electron-positron pair. Here, $q$ is the 4-momentum of a virtual photon.

I see that $q^2 \ge 2m^2$ is a necessary condition for the creation of a real electron-positron pair, but are there other necessary conditions and are they sufficient? If not, why do they imply that pair creation only happens at $q^2 \ge 4m^2$?

Comment: How did you come up with $q^2\ge 2m^2$?

Comment: $q^2 \ge (p_{e^-} + p_{e^+})^2 = 2m^2 + 2p_{e^-}\cdot p_{e^+}$

Comment: So what happened to the second term on the right hand side?

Comment: I see. If the pair is created at rest, $p_{e^-}\cdot p_{e^+} = m^2$.

Comment: The optical theorem never lies...

Answer (score 2):

$q^2 \geq 4m_e^2$ or equivalently in the center of mass frame $q^0 \geq 2m_e$ is a sufficient condition in the sense that
$$
(\Gamma(\gamma^*(q) \rightarrow e^- e^+))_{\text{CoM}} \propto \Theta(q^0 - 2m_e^2) f(q^0)
$$
where $f(q^0)$ is a non-zero function, $\gamma^*$ denotes a virtual photon and $\Gamma$ is the decay rate (verifying this a straightforward exercise).

You can see in your one-loop expression for the photon self energy that this function has a branch cut starting at $q^2 > 4m_e^2$, if this is not clear look here [Branch cut singularity in photon propagator at one loop](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/580068/branch-cut-singularity-in-photon-propagator-at-one-loop?rq=1). That this is true also for the full self energy follows from the optical theorem, which states
$$
\text{Im }\Pi(q^2) \propto \sum_X \Gamma(\gamma^*(q^2) \rightarrow X),
$$
where the sum goes over all states $X$ in the Hilbertspace. This implies that the photon self energy $\Pi(q^2)$ acquires an imaginary part if $\gamma^*(q^2)$ can decay into some state (i.e. if some decay rate is non-zero), and this is possible in QED for only if $q^2 > 4m_e^2$. Since we have the identity
$$
\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0}(\Pi(q^2+i\epsilon)-\Pi(q^2-i\epsilon)) = 2i \text{Im } \Pi(q^2)
$$
you can see that we have branch cut on the real line starting at $q^2 = 4m_e^2$.